# flutter sentry The function 'runZonedGuarded' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, sentry

I am trying to add sentry in my flutter project.
From the documentation, i see I have to do it like this

```
runZonedGuarded(
 () => runApp(MyApp(flutterI18nDelegate)),
   (error, stackTrace) {
try {
  sentry.captureException(
    exception: error,
    stackTrace: stackTrace,
  );
  print('Error sent to sentry.io: $error');
} catch (e) {
  print('Sending report to sentry.io failed: $e');
  print('Original error: $error');
}
});
```

But I am getting this error

`The function 'runZonedGuarded' isn't defined. Try importing the library that defines 'runZonedGuarded', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named` 
[image]

Thank you.

My dart and flutter version

```
Flutter 1.20.2 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision bbfbf1770c (8 weeks ago) • 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
Engine • revision 9d5b21729f
```

Tools • Dart 2.9.1

Comment: you need *import 'dart:async';*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`runZonedGuarded` is defined on `dart:async`.

The complete snippet is:

```dart
import 'dart:async'; 

// Wrap your 'runApp(MyApp())' as follows:

void main() async {
  runZonedGuarded(
    () => runApp(MyApp()),
    (error, stackTrace) {
      await sentry.captureException(
        exception: error,
        stackTrace: stackTrace,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

[We've added to the docs](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-docs/pull/2444).